# Перестал работать Emmet в SublimeText3

Tags: sublime-text-3, emmet

Увлекся установкой плагинов, поставил с десяток, но, увидел, в какой-то момент, что Emmet не работет.

Я уже пытался найти ответ в сети, пожалйста не предлагайте сменить расширение-я работаю в файле .html, галочка view/sintax/html стоит.

Пытался поправить это в Preferences/Key bindings, Preferences/Package Settings/Emmet/Key bindings, переписывая ключи ТАБ в User,но не поборол.

Снес Саблайм, поставил заново программу, плагин, ничего не изменилось.
!+ТАБ не работает, .nameClass+ТАБ не работает, f+ТАБ вдруг выдает".<филдсет></филдсет>". div+ТАБ тоже ".<див></див>"(с точкой!).
НО! html+ТАБ  отрисовывает шапку DOCTYPE со всеми тегами правильно!
Странно, где-то переопределился ТАБ. Помогите, пожалуйста, сил моих нет.

Comment: Спасибо, я это читал. это все не работает.

Comment: Возможно конфликт плагинов

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ сам, пишу для остальных страждущих.
1.Удалил плагин через Package Control.
2.Зашел на страницу Emmet на github](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#how-to-install).
3.Скачал архив, поставил вручную как написано, все работает.